# Having trouble retrieving and displaying model data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

Currently working on a prototype for an iOS app where I have a profile tab open and a button modally presents a new view controller where you can edit changes to the profile then save them. Only problem is when saving changes to that particular profile and returning to the root controller no changes were visibly made;

```
class ProfileStore {
    static let shared = ProfileStore()
    
    init() {}
    
    var profiles: [Profile] = []
    var userProfile = Profile(fullName: "", profilePicture: UIImage(named: "goku_icon")!, description: "", password: "")
    
    func retrieveProfile(accountPassword: String) -> Profile {
        let filteredProfile = ProfileStore.shared.profiles.filter { (Profile) -> Bool in
            return Profile.password == accountPassword
        }
        userProfile = filteredProfile[0]
        return userProfile
    }
    
    func saveToProfile(accountPassword: String, activeProfile: Profile) -> Profile{
        var filteredProfile = ProfileStore.shared.profiles.filter { (Profile) -> Bool in
            return Profile.password == accountPassword
        }
        filteredProfile[0] = activeProfile
        userProfile = filteredProfile[0]
        return userProfile
    }
}
```

Above is a singleton which I use to store and retrieve all of the user profiles of type "Profile". Where .profiles is essentially a pretend database.

```
@IBAction func createAccount(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let newAccount = Account(username: usernameField.text!, password: passwordField.text!)
        
        AccountStore.shared.accounts.append(newAccount)
        
        let newProfile = Profile(fullName: "Full Name", profilePicture: UIImage(named: "goku_icon")!, description: "About me", password: AccountStore.shared.accounts.last!.password)
        
        ProfileStore.shared.profiles.append(newProfile)
    }
```

Above here is what happens when a user creates an account and profile on a specific view controller

```
@IBAction func loginToProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        AccountStore.shared.login(loginUsername: usernameLogin.text!, loginPassword: passwordLogin.text!)
        let currentAccount = AccountStore.shared.userAccount
        
        ProfileStore.shared.retrieveProfile(accountPassword: currentAccount.password)
    }
```

Here you see the login method of the login view controller. After this we move to a profile view controller with the login @IBAction.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePictureView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullNameView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bioView: UITextView!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        makeRounded(imageView: profilePictureView)
        
        ProfileStore.shared.retrieveProfile(accountPassword: ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.password)
        
        profilePictureView.image = ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.profilePicture
        fullNameView.text = ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.fullName
        bioView.text = ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.description
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwindToProfile(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) { 
    }
```

Finally there is a button which modally presents the vc where you edit the profile;

```
class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var editBio: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var editFullName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var chosenImage: UIImageView!
    
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        makeRounded(imageView: chosenImage)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func imagePicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
        if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            chosenImage.image = selectedImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // Want to save changes to this particular user profile in .profiles our "database"
    
    @IBAction func saveChanges(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        if let newChosenImage = chosenImage.image {
            // Call a method from Profile store which saves these changes to userAccount
            ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.profilePicture = newChosenImage
            ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.fullName = editFullName.text!
            ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.description = editBio.text!
            
            ProfileStore.shared.saveToProfile(accountPassword: ProfileStore.shared.userProfile.password, activeProfile: ProfileStore.shared.userProfile)
        }
        
    }
```

the saveChanges() @IBAction is attached to a save changes button which is attached to the unwindSegue method in the root vc. My main issue is that the changes being made in the edit vc either arent being displayed to the root vc properly or the data changes arent being saved/ retrieved properly. Not sure which one. Open to all answers and criticism.

Comment: Either have a segue linked directly to the button or have an `@IBAction` but not both. The order of execution of the two together isn't defined. You will probably find that the unwind segue is being performed and `viewWillAppear` is running before the updated data has been saved. You should trigger the unwind in code with `performSegue` after the update code has run.

Comment: It would appear to not have made a difference. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Set a breakpoint to confirm that `viewWillAppear` is being called. You could also refresh your view in `unwindToProfile`.

Comment: It seems that viewWillAppear is being called... very strange

Comment: Then set a breakpoint in `saveChanges` too. Make sure the order of execution is what you expect. Examine the variables in the debugger to make sure the values are what you expect.

Comment: I figured it out. Will post the answer soon.